# Peewee MySQL server has gone away error

Tags: python, peewee

Is there any way to catch this exception and reinitialize the connection?

Or possibly tune `peewee` to avoid this exception.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL defines an idle timeout, after which time an idle connection is terminated by the server. This happens with long-lived peewee connections.

To automatically attempt reconnecting after this error (or a couple other related errors) you should use the ReconnectMixin helper in `playhouse.shortcuts`.

It defines a couple error conditions on which the connection should be re-opened and retried:

```
from peewee import MySQLDatabase
from playhouse.shortcuts import ReconnectMixin

class ReconnectMySQLDatabase(ReconnectMixin, MySQLDatabase):
    pass

db = ReconnectMySQLDatabase('my_app', ...)
```

Comment: Sorry for my wrong/incorrect answer below, but I didn't see this mentioned anywhere in the latest docs. Could you please update the docs?

Comment: This is the correct answer. A note for other peewee fan. Input argument of  `ReconnectMySQLDatabase` is the same as `MySQLDatabase`

Comment: I am running Flask with an Application Factory, is there documentation on ReconnectMixin and environments similar to mine? I've been unable to find the ReconnectMixin on the readthedocs.io website.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Link](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#managing-your-database) You should close the connection manually. otherwise peewee doesn't close it.

```
db = MySQLDatabase('database_name', user='www-data', charset='utf8mb4')

# this is not necessary, because peewee open the connection automatically
def before_execute_any_query():
    db.connect()

# after execute all queries and complete the action
def after_execute_query():
    db.close()
```

This error occurs when for a long time the connection remain open without any usage.

Comment: How does this word?

Comment: This error occurs when the connection remain open and your script doesn't use the opened connection. to avoid this, the simplest way is closing the connections and let the peewee opens it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pooled mysql connection from peewee's extension library: playhouse. see [docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html)

Comment: If we are using PooledMySQLDatabase , this issue mentioned here will be fixed ?
Or even for PooledMySQLDatabase , we need to use ReconnectMixin ?
@coleifer